# Why cannot read folders on LiveCD?

Tags: live-cd

How do I move a folder to an external drive using a live disc?

When I try it says:

> the folder cannot be handled because you do not have permission to
>   read it.

---

Thanks for the help everyone. I got it copied by using sudo su nautilus.

Comment: Does [this](http://askubuntu.com/a/395035/62483) helps?

Comment: If you don't have permission to move it, you probably should just be copying it - not moving it. Which folder are you trying to move?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No need for a live disk. You could type `gksu nautilus` in a terminal window. Nautilus will open giving you super-user privileges, and you'll be able to move whatever you want wherever you want it.

There might be open files that will give you trouble, depending on what you want to move, but you shouldn't move those anyway.

Comment: I think one live disks you may need to install *(it won't install to disk, just to memory whilst your running the disk - something like that)* `gksu` - use `sudo apt-get install gksu`.